# How can I send POST requests in a secure manner to a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, ruby-on-rails-5, csrf

I am trying to add a layer of security to my POST requests.

I have multiple ruby script that doing Curl Post Request to my rails server. The concern here is having an attacker send a big batch of requests at the same time. Blocking our server and costing us lots of money.

Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: 99.9% of applications are also susceptible to this but it really doesn't happen all that often.

But you'll want to look into [Rack::Attack](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack) or similar rate-limiting solutions.

Comment: Isn't your question about how to handle a denial of service attack? The title seems mis-matched.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the authenticity token rails automatically generates in its forms as a type of very basic captcha for your CLI scripts. Keep in mind that the point of authenticity tokens is to avoid CSRF attacks not DOS attacks so if you are worried about bots taking up bandwidth this wont help, but if your concern is that only 'authorized' requests get through you could use the tokens. Obviously the best solution for that would be to have full User authentication and authorization for your routes and have a user set up for your scripts and generating a JWT for the user. Once you have the authenticity token or a JWT you can just add them to your POST.

You can read how the authenticity tokens work here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html and add the authenticity_token key to your POST. If your scripts are running in the rails environment creating a session and getting a valid token is easy

`app.get '/<some_model>s/new'`

`token = app.session[:_csrf_token]`

then use that token in your post

`app.post '/<some_model>s', params: {authenticity_token: token}`